# Bootstrap container with content and facebook buttons on the side

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap and have all my content in a container; this centers all the content just the way i want it. The problem is that i also want a fixed bar on the right side with width 250px with facebook like button and maybe some text.

What i also want is that when i re-size the browser to mobile view the whole right bar will appear on the bottom right after the container.

I have tried to make rows around the containers but that did not work work

```
<div class = "row" >
   <div  class = "col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class ="container">
        ...
      </div>
   </div>

   <div  class = "col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class ="container">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also tried to float a div to the right, but that wont work in the mobile view..

I have googled this for hours, downloaded webpages to see source code, and tried a lot of things i cant even remember with no result. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I have found a solution to this and i will post my code when i am allowed to by stackoverflow. I do not have enough reputation to answer my own question i have to wait 8 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that my question might be a bit unclear. And i see that my code attempts are rubbish. But i found a solution:

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "row">
       <div class = "col-lg-9">
           <div class = "panel panel-default">
               <div class = "panel-body">
                 Main content
               </div>
           </div>
       </div> 

       <div class = "col-lg-3">
           <div class = "list-group">
            Side Bar Content
           </div>
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

This will make a main content container with a bar on the side for different elements.
Coder's Guide on YouTube have a great tutorial for this. ( http://goo.gl/ZfH6rk )

Answer (score 0):

Here is an fiddle if it can help you :

**bootply**  http://www.bootply.com/117047

**html**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 leftarea">
    left area
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 right-atea">
      <div class="row tofix">    
        <div class="well col-xs-12 rightfixed"> 
          right fixed
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.leftarea{
  height:950px;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
  }


    .rightfixed{
      background-color:red;
          height:250px;

        }

    @media (min-width: 940px) { 

    .rightfixed{
        position: fixed;
            width:250px;
      }

     }
```